# Can we use Android TTS from web pages?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How do I use Android TTS API's from the web page?

Comment: Are you looking for an internal "web page" (i.e., one that's packaged with the program) or one that's really on the web?

Comment: one from the web, but a webpage is a webpage, how does it matter, I just want to use TTS from the webpage, does android browser have some hook to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can't in the Android Browser, but you can in a `WebView` packaged in your app (as fiXedd alluded to).

Look into [WebView#addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for details on how you can expose a shim between a `WebView` and a Java class (which could expose TTS functions).

Comment: This feels like half an answer.  It would be better if it also gave an example of how this might work in practice.